# Creating external content type using wcf service for SP Online BCS using SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type, wcf

I have created WCF Service and I am able to generate WSDL URL and Endpoints when I use SharePoint designer 2013 to Create external content type to connect to SharePoint online BCS It does not show any error 
but the connection is also not getting established as shown below image 
I have all the required permissions in office 365 meta store 
[image]

Comment: I am not seeing any error on the screenshot either. Which connection are you using to create the External Content Type? Right-click the "GetEmployee" method in the Data Source Explorer, and then click "New Read Item Operation" on the context menu. Any error during this process? See the tutorials here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg318616(v%3Doffice.14)#creating-external-content-types-from-web-services
http://sharepointwithamol.blogspot.com/2016/01/bcs-with-sharepoint-online.html

Comment: hi thank you for your help it's working fine now

Comment: I have another question does the SQL server required to have public access for BCS to work?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Azure? I am not sure "public access" for BCS in SharePoint Online is even possible.